# How to add specific days to existing date column in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table Products with column 'Purchase_date'. 
I want to view the Purchase date column as updated by adding 10 days to the existing purchase date of a particular product say 'Lamp' using sql.
How to do this?

I tried this:

```
select purchase_date,date add(purchase_date,10) as updated_purchase_day 
from product 
where product_name= 'Lamp' ;
```

This shows error like:

```
ORA-00904: "DATE_ADD": invalid identifier 
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" 
*Cause:     
*Action: Error at Line: 448 Column: 22
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i48042

Answer (score 2):

Adding a day in Oracle works like this:

```
select purchase_date, (purchase_date + 10) as updated_purchase_day
from product where product_name= 'Lamp';
```

Or

```
select purchase_date, (purchase_date + INTERVAL '10' DAY) as updated_purchase_day
from product where product_name= 'Lamp';
```

Comment: if instead of '10' the value is coming out from another column of the table  How to specify column name?

Answer (score -1):

If you use MSSQL, you can try this query:

```
select purchase_date, DATEADD(DD, 10, purchase_date) as updated_purchase_day 
from product 
where product_name= 'Lamp' ;
```